# Can we Change the definition of predefined functions? Then How to Prevent it?

Tags: javascript

As I understand from my practice (in the Google Chrome Console), we can change the definition of predefined functions. Let me explain through code:

```
function alert(){
  return 2+2;
  }
```

and I am calling `alert("hi")`, it is returning 4, it's Ok, as we have defined.
But, even when I call `window.alert("hi")`, it is returning 4, which is unexpected (for me).

Here I just created a new function, I have not mentioned any **object name** or **Prototype** property, but still it is overriding the **window** object properties itself.

My doubt is, if we change the definition of the function, will it override the definitions of a function with the same name in all the objects??

Let's say I have two objects `objA` and `objB`, both are having a function named `strange()`. Now I am defining a function strange() in the outside of both the objects. Then, whether it will override the definition of `strange()` in both `objA` nad `objB`? If so, why?

If so, how to prevent this? means how to prevent the overriding in all the objects?

Thanks in advance...!!!!

Answer (score 3):

No - by declaring `function alert()` you are redefining `window.alert()` function because the default scope is window

```
var newObj = {
    alert: function() {
        return "this is a functino on my newObj object";
    }
};

function alert() {
    return 2 + 2;
}

console.log(alert());
console.log(window.alert());
console.log(newObj.alert());
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason defining alert overrides the window property is because you declared it in the global context; anything declared in the global context will, by default, attach itself to `window`. To not override the `window` object, declare your function inside another function (or use a different name):

```
// This creates an anonymous function
(function() {
  // Since alert is defined in this function (not the global scope)
  // It won't override window.alert
  function alert() { /* Do something */ }
})();
// You can no longer access the old alert here, so alert will refer to window.alert
```

In addition, if you add alert to a specific object, it will not change the alert of any other object, unless you use a `with` statement (considered bad practice).

```
var myNamespace = {
  alert: function() { /* Custom alert */ }
}
// Will not change myNamespace.alert
function alert() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think so - with the alert function, the "window." prefix is assumed so really window.alert() and alert() are the same thing. I guess it's a short-cut to stop you havign to type window. all the time.

Regarding your other example, objA.strange() isn't related to objB.strange() (assuming objA and objB are in fact different objects).

the function strange() outside of both these objects is actually in window.strange() (it's implied) so again it's a different function under a different object.

You can, I gather, use prototype to redefine  native JS functions, but this is normally undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a variable or function in the default scope in javascript (creating a function directly inside a `<script>` tag for instance), it is considered part of the window object (if javascript is executed in a browser environment).

So, when you call (the default) `alert`, you arev actually calling `window.alert`.

> Let's say I have two objects objA and objB, both are having a function
>   named strange(). Now I am defining a function strange() in the outside
>   of both the objects. Then, whether it will override the definition of
>   strange() in both objA nad objB

A definition of `strange` outside both the object scope (closure) will not impact the definition of the function (method) in the object. But if you define `strange` within the object again, the latter one will shadow the previous one.

It boils down to the scope of the function and the closure withing which the function (or variable) is defined.

See also

- [Functions and function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) from MDN. This will answer most of your questions
- [Closure](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#48) from John Resig's [Learning Advanced Javascript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/)

Comment: Thank you very much for giving links.